# Resolve recursive dependences using substitution method

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, computer-science, recursion

Resolve recursive dependences using substitution method and prove it with mathematical induction:

```
1.T(1) = 1
T(n) = T(n – 1) + n for n > 1

2. T(1) = 0
T(n) = T(n/2) + 1 for even numbers n > 1
T(n) = T((n + 1)/2) + 1 for odd numbers n > 1
```

*In the second point, it's enough that you'll get the solution for **n=2^k**
and natural number **k**.*

I don't understand the substitution method yet.

In the first point, I've got:

```
T(n) = n(n-1) + 1
```

But this doesn't seem to be right because proof says it's wrong. And what does it mean that: *it's enough that you'll get the solution for **n=2^k**
and natural number **k***.

Comment: The reason your answer to the first question is wrong is not that "proof" says that it's wrong: the reason it's wrong is that it's wrong. E.g., it gives you $T(3)=7$, whereas the recursion gives you $T(3)=6$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, so what would be the correct one?

Comment: Well, I could tell you the answer, but wouldn't you rather learn a method so you could answer similar questions yourself?

Comment: @GerryMyerson, of course, but I've tried and I just can't do it, so the answer or explanation would help me to understand this topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's rewrite the first as T(n + 1) = T(n) + n + 1.
Then T(1) = 1, T(2) = 1 + 2, T(3) = do you see the pattern?